# Make name variable print the corrent name with an automated email

Tags: python, pandas, list, automation, smtp

I've been trying to make a python script to send a happy birthday email on a given date, that notifies me who it sent an email to via text message.

I have 3 files.

First I have a brithdays.csv file which I enter all the birthday data that is going to use.
Here's an example of what's inside the file:

```
name,email,year,month,day
Ivy,Testemail@mail.com,1,3,25 
Rose,Testemail@mail.com,1,3,28 
Kimberly,Testemail@mail.com,1,4,10
```

Then I have a letter template which the script reads and replaces [NAME] with the name in the CSV file :

Greetings,

Im wishing [NAME] a very happy birthday! [NAME], &#128522 I hope you enjoy your day and wishing you more life.

Thank you,

And then I have my actual code

```
############## IMPORTS ##############
import smtplib
import datetime as dtime
import pandas as pd
import random
from time import strftime
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

############## Reading Data and Check Current Day & Month ##############

# READ CSV BIRTHDAY FILE
df = pd.read_csv("birthdays.csv")

# PRINT CURRENT DAY
current_day = dtime.datetime.now().day
current_month = dtime.datetime.now().month


##################ENTER LOGIN HERE#############################

LOGIN = "EMAIL"
PASS = "PASSWORD"



############## LOGIC ##############

# save the rows that has the current day in new variable
new_df = df.loc[df['day'] == current_day]

# check the length of new_df of the current month so if the result is larger than 1
# so there is birthdays on this day
if len(new_df.loc[new_df['month'] == current_month]) > 0:
    
    # check the length of people having birthday in this day 
    for i in range(len(new_df.loc[new_df['month'] == current_month])):
        
        # OPEN BIRTHDAY TEMPLATE
        with open(f"./letter_1.txt") as letter_file:
            
            # READING FILE
            letter_contents = letter_file.read()

            #CREATE NAME VARIABLE
            name = df["name"][i]
            
            # replace [NAME] with actual name on the data
            if len(new_df["name"]) > 1:
                the_letter = letter_contents.replace("[NAME]", new_df["name"][i])
                the_email = new_df["email"][i]
            else:
                the_letter = letter_contents.replace("[NAME]", new_df["name"].item())
                the_email = new_df["email"].item()
                
                
                
                
                
               
            
        
            # SMTPLIB LOGIN TO SEND EMAIL
            # CONNECTION
            with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.outlook.com") as con:
                
                # START
                con.starttls()
                
                # LOGIN
                con.login(user=LOGIN, password=PASS)
                
                # create the msg
                msg = MIMEText(the_letter, 'html')
                msg["From"] = LOGIN
                msg["To"] = the_email 
                msg["Subject"] = "Happy Birthday " + name + "!!!"
                msg["Cc"] = "CC EMAILS"
                
                # SEND EMAIL
                con.send_message(msg)
                
                #SENDS TEXT MESSAGE CONFIRMATION
                msg = MIMEText ("Sent Happy Birthday Email to " + name + " on " + str(text.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p')))
                msg["From"] = LOGIN
                msg["To"] = "VERIZONPHONENUMBER@vtext.com"
                
                # SEND TEXT
                con.send_message(msg)
                
                # LOGS OUT OF EMAIL
                con.quit()
```

I think the issue lies in Line 45 where I create the name variable.

My issue is that every time it sends an email, the name in the Subject of the email and in the text message I receive it's the first name of the list.

For example if I run the script, the email would look something like this

Happy Birthday Ivy!!!

Greetings,

Im wishing Rose a very happy birthday! Rose, &#128522 I hope you enjoy your day and wishing you more life.

I'm trying to make the name that appears on the subject match with the name that appears on the body of text.

Answer (score 0):

```py
msg = MIMEText ("Sent Happy Birthday Email to " + name + " on " + str(text.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p')))
```

Here you are using the `name` variable when generating the body but earlier in your code you have:

```py
name = df["name"][i]
```

Which grabs the name from the unfiltered DataFrame but you use the filtered DataFrame to generate the subject line here:

```py
# replace [NAME] with actual name on the data
if len(new_df["name"]) > 1:
    the_letter = letter_contents.replace("[NAME]", new_df["name"][i])
    the_email = new_df["email"][i]
else:
    the_letter = letter_contents.replace("[NAME]", new_df["name"].item())
    the_email = new_df["email"].item()
```

The i-th element in the filtered DataFrame might not be the i-th element in your original DataFrame so you need to declare `name` as follows:

```py
name = new_df["name"][i]
```

Comment: I get this error:
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\base.py", line 3621, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "birthday.py", line 46, in <module>
    name = new_df["name"][i]
  File "\series.py", line 958, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "\series.py", line 1069, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0```